# Attachment on mail

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to attach a sheet on a mail, as a pdf file. But it's obviously not working (indeed, i'm there).

I know that the file is created (if I put a breakpoint or I remove the `Kill fname` the file is well created.

The mail is sent, with the body, the subject, from and to the good email address but the file is not attached. I don't know why, and it's making me crazy.

If anyone knows the soluce, please help me ! Thanks. Clément.

*here's the macro. Creating the .pdf file, and then creating the email*

```
fname = "testFile.pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=fname, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Call Open_Outlook

On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = "myMail@my.me"
    .Body = "Body"
    .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .Attachments.Add fname
    .Send
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
Kill fname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the location of the PDF file, not just the name.

`"C:\TEMP\testFile.pdf"` or wherever you are saving it.

Comment: Ok. It's working. My bad. I don't know why but before, like one month ago, it was working, even if the compelte path of the file wasn't specified. But today, no. For me, it was a big advantage because the path depends on the computer you are. Anyway, thanks @jcarroll